# Prevent downloading with htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, fonts, download, hotlinking

I've searched around but have found no solutions.

I have a directory with all my fonts (svg, eot, woff, ttf, otf) in which I'd like to restrict downloading. Is there a way with .htaccess or..?

Edit: I am using Wordpress

Comment: Are any of them going to be used client-side?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you want the fonts to be useable within a webpage, then there isn't a way.

The browser has to be able to download them in order to display them.

Answer (score 0):

Simple hotlinking example here: http://www.easymodrewrite.com/example-hotlinking

Answer (score 0):

Put a `.htaccess` file into that directory with the following:

```
Order allow,deny
Deny from all
```